# How to replace letters in string to dashes but not spaces

Tags: javascript

I am creating hangman and with this code I replace the content in string with dashes, but some strings are two words -- "hello world" -- which the output is - - - - - - - - - - - 11 characters instead of ten. How do I avoid replacing the space?

```
var stateNames = ["alabama", "alaska", "arizona", "california", 
  "colorado", "connecticut", "delaware", "florida", "georgia", 
  "hawaii",  
  "idaho", "illinois", "indiana", "iowa", "kansas", "kentucky", 
  "louisiana", "maine", "maryland", "massachusetts", "michigan", 
  "minnesota", "mississippi", "missouri", "montana", "nebraska", 
  "nevada", "new hampshire", "new jersey", "new mexico", "new york", 
  "north carolina", "north dakota", "ohio", "oklahoma", "oregon", 
  "pennsylvania", "rhode island", "south carolina", "south dakota", 
  "tennessee", "texas", "utah", "vermont", "virgina", "washington", 
  "west virgina", "wisconsin", "wyoming"];

function beginGame() {
    var randomPick = stateNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * 
    stateNames.length)];

    var replaceWithDash = [];

    for (i = 0; i < randomPick.length; i++){
    replaceWithDash[i] = "_";
}
console.log(randomPick);
console.log(replaceWithDash);
}

beginGame();
```

Comment: There isn't anything in your code that says you tried to solve the issue...

Comment: Do you want "hello world" to become "----- -----" or "----------"?

Comment: `s.replace(/\S/g,'-')` might be close…

Comment: @RobG Thank you! I was using replace but (/\s/g, "-") instead which I realized it was going the opposite!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you're looping over your letters, you'll want to check whether or not the target letter is a space or not. If it's not a space, replace it with a dash. If it *is* a space, however, you should replace it with a space instead.

Note that considering you're making use of the second array `replaceWithDash` rather than simply replacing the letters, you'll need to explicitly state that the letter in the new array should contain a space, rather than simply only running the logic when there is not a space. As such, the `else` is required in the following (or else you'd end up with `undefined` indexes):

```
for (i = 0; i < randomPick.length; i++) {
  if (randomPick[i] !== " ") {
    replaceWithDash[i] = "_";
  }
  else {
    replaceWithDash[i] = " ";
  }
}
```

This can be seen in the following:

```js
var stateNames = ["alabama", "alaska", "arizona", "california",
  "colorado", "connecticut", "delaware", "florida", "georgia",
  "hawaii",
  "idaho", "illinois", "indiana", "iowa", "kansas", "kentucky",
  "louisiana", "maine", "maryland", "massachusetts", "michigan",
  "minnesota", "mississippi", "missouri", "montana", "nebraska",
  "nevada", "new hampshire", "new jersey", "new mexico", "new york",
  "north carolina", "north dakota", "ohio", "oklahoma", "oregon",
  "pennsylvania", "rhode island", "south carolina", "south dakota",
  "tennessee", "texas", "utah", "vermont", "virgina", "washington",
  "west virgina", "wisconsin", "wyoming"
];

function beginGame() {
  var randomPick = stateNames[Math.floor(Math.random() *
    stateNames.length)];

  var replaceWithDash = [];

  for (i = 0; i < randomPick.length; i++) {
    if (randomPick[i] !== " ") {
      replaceWithDash[i] = "_";
    }
    else {
      replaceWithDash[i] = " ";
    }
  }
  console.log(randomPick);
  console.log(replaceWithDash);
}

beginGame();
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Or `replaceWithDash[i] =  randomPick[i] == ' '? ' ' : '_';` ;-)

Comment: If you want to get really fancy with ternaries, that would work, yes :P Personally I get a little confused with ternaries, and prefer readability over fewer lines of code :)

Comment: This does. I was thinking of doing something like this but confused myself in the process. >.< Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, basically you need to check if the value you are inserting into the array is a space or not. If you want to do something different when it is a space, you can add an else statement to do so. Here you will just iterate over that element of the array and then use filter_array to clean it up.

```
  var stateNames = ["alabama", "alaska", "arizona", "california", 
      "colorado", "connecticut", "delaware", "florida", "georgia", 
      "hawaii",  
      "idaho", "illinois", "indiana", "iowa", "kansas", "kentucky", 
      "louisiana", "maine", "maryland", "massachusetts", "michigan", 
      "minnesota", "mississippi", "missouri", "montana", "nebraska", 
      "nevada", "new hampshire", "new jersey", "new mexico", "new york", 
      "north carolina", "north dakota", "ohio", "oklahoma", "oregon", 
      "pennsylvania", "rhode island", "south carolina", "south dakota", 
      "tennessee", "texas", "utah", "vermont", "virgina", "washington", 
      "west virgina", "wisconsin", "wyoming"];

    function beginGame() {
        var randomPick = stateNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * 
        stateNames.length)];

        var replaceWithDash = [];

        for (i = 0; i < randomPick.length; i++){
                    if(randomPick.charAt(i-1) != " "){
                       replaceWithDash[i] = "_";
                     }
                 }




    console.log(randomPick);
    console.log(filter_array(replaceWithDash));
}
beginGame();   


 function filter_array(test_array) {
        var index = -1,
            arr_length = test_array ? test_array.length : 0,
            resIndex = -1,
            result = [];

        while (++index < arr_length) {
            var value = test_array[index];

            if (value) {
                result[++resIndex] = value;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```